# Motherboard temperature reaches 124° C?

Tags: motherboard, cooling, temperature, diagnostic

This is a brand new PC build (only a few days old.) There are plenty of fans in the case, but after a few hours of playing [Skyrim](http://www.elderscrolls.com/skyrim/), this is what [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) reports:

[image]

My usual motherboard idle temperature is 60° C. This is really scaring me, and isn't something I've diagnosed before. What should I do?

Comment: When it shows that temp it is non moving?  Because many of the softwares will display 0,124,125 or something when they no longer are properly getting a reading from the chip, or via the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sensor is not necessarily broken, the software could do bad interpretation of its data.

Check the temperatures with [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfscreenshots.php).

Comment: You can't meassure temps with CPU-Z. You need HWMonitor(talking about CPUID) for that.

Comment: @bamboon I was about to say the same, but I don't think the down vote is necessary; his reasoning is correct. Speccy was showing incorrect data... other software shows my Motherboard at 28° C and Motherboard Auxiliary (?) at 36° C.

Answer (score 3):

Before you take the motherboard back to the shop due to Speccy not recognizing the correct temperature, let me add my two cents.

I have the exact same problem, the exact same temperature, even though my CPU and graphics card are running about at about 36C because I went overboard with case fans.

However, and this is what I feel may be relevant, I also have the exact same motherboard as you. Now, do we both have versions that function perfectly otherwise but where the MB temp sensor is broken, or could there be a problem with how this particular motherboard talks with Speccy?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your motherboard's sensor is borked, because I think 124 degrees is extremely high, I think even past the dangerzone temperature where normally your system should shut down. The reason for this is that all the other components read out a relative low temperature. If your mobo was 124 degrees it would heat up the other components a lot more.

I think you better take it back to your shop to exchange it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Temps Speccy]

Speccy is good for checking hardware but not for the temperatures. My cpu was under full load, according to speccy, over 150 degrees Celsius. According to coretemp it's now 33 degrees Celsius and speccy says it's 82 degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 1):

Put a normal **glass thermometer** on the board's heatsink (glass so nonconductive) to check if that's really the temperature (sincerely doubt it... probably don't even need a thermometer at that claimed temperature, just see if you're burned by getting close). If that was the real temperature of your motherboard, speccy probably wouldn't even be working (and likely not many other parts of your computer).

If, by some crazy situation that this readout is possible and accurate (probably requiring extremely hardened electronics and heavily overclocked chip set pushed beyond its normal spec, at which point I'd be inclined to ask you to call in a few more professionals to help you maintain and update the nuclear launch systems out of personal interest), my suggestion is spraying lightly with **liquid nitrogen**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with speccy. My cpu sensor was telling me it was running at 80°C in idle when it was really running at 40°C.

I switched to HWInfo64.